# How do I play new videos from my YouTube subscriptions as a playlist?

Tags: youtube

I am subscribed to many channels on YouTube and I would like to be able to press "play" and let all the videos play on my Windows laptop one after another as if I'm watching TV. This is such an essential feature that it is almost mindblowing that YouTube doesn't have it.

What workarounds are there to let me achieve this?

Comment: videos you don't have seen ?

Comment: Well you could say that. I would like to be able to play the new videos from newest to oldest by clicking one button. If it only shows me ones I haven't seen, that would be even better.

Answer (score 3):

The only one I'm aware of yet is this one: [auto-youtube-subscription-playlist-2](https://github.com/Elijas/auto-youtube-subscription-playlist-2)

Disclaimer: I'm the author, feel free to give feedback or improve upon it.